# How to translate this JavaScript Code into jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, translate

I've got some code in JavaScript, that I would like to get translated into jQuery. I have been browsing the net for some hours now and tried to figure it out by myself but with no success. So I came here.

```
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
    var dp1 = document.getElementById('dp1');
    if(event.target != dp1 && event.target.parentNode != dp1){
        dp1.style.height = "0px";
        dp1.style.width = "0px";
    }
});
```

Comment: May I ask why you would like to use jQuery?

Comment: I guess it's shorter?

Comment: @JustinSeidel: It's only shorter when it's shorter. It's not when it's not. And if you count the library itself, it's nearly always much, much longer.

Comment: rudeness will leave you with none... I was answering you. Now I'm not doing it anymore.

Comment: You won't make your code any more performance by loading in a needless dependency if that's what you're concerned with. We ask questions to better understand your problem. Depending on compatibility requirements (looking at addEventListener) you probably won't want jQuery.

Comment: I would like to know, where exactly I got rude. Another thing I can't figure out right now. I was just telling him/her, that I want to have answers (not in form of questions) relating to my own question.

Comment: Anyway, I would be grateful if someone could be so nice and just translate this piece of code into jQuery. Doesn't matter if jQuery is a big library, way longer itself than JavaScript or w/e. I just want to have jQuery code.

Comment: You have to understand that everyone here is a volunteer. No one gets paid a cent. So the least you can do is answer what we ask you about your question in the most polite way possible.

Comment: @JustinSeidel: Well we didn't ask for your question either, so we're perfectly comfortable with asking you questions. However, this isn't a code translation service. Show where you're stuck and you may get some help.

Comment: SO is not a place where you get people to write your code for you. Go learn jQuery, this is pretty simple stuff if you read up about jQuery event listeners you should get it in no time.

Comment: Aké............

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow isn't a code conversion tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `jQuery` is `JavaScript`.

Most people try not to load it in their projects, to lower the overhead it brings so, usually, the request is the opposite of what you're asking. One way of reducing this overhead is to load `jQuery` in its lite form.

But that's not to say `jQuery` is all bad.

Besides shorter syntax, the special thing about `jQuery`, its best and worst feature, depending on where you look from, is that it brings a lot of flexibility to `JavaScript` and that's preventing programmers from understanding `js` limitations. It's help, but it's constraint. For example, I never needed to learn closures before coding clean `JavaScript`, because `jQuery` would add them silently to my constructs whenever they were needed.

A clearly positive thing about `jQuery` is it provides quirks and workarounds for a few browser inconsistencies one doesn't have to and shouldn't need to know about, much like [`autoprefixer`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) takes away most of the pain of prefixing `CSS`.

That being said, here's what I believe to be a streamlined version of your code, in `jQuery`. You should only use it if you're already loading `jQuery` in your project, IMHO.

```js
$(window).on('mouseup', function(e){
  if (! $(e.target).closest('#dp1').is('#dp1')) {
    $('#dp1').css({
      height: 0,
      width: 0
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Translate the code to jQuery has no sense, this code is longer, slower and has heavy dependencies:

```
$(window).on("mouseup", function(event) {
    var dp1 = $('#dp1');
    if(this != dp1.get(0) && $(this).parent().get(0) != dp1.get(0)){
        dp1.css("height", "0px");
        dp1.css("width", "0px");
    }
});
```

Comment: Really, I don't care. Just thank you so very much for your time and giving me what I was needing. Thank you. Really, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try with the following code.

```
$(document).mouseup(function(event){
    var dp1 = $('#dp1');
  if(event.target != dp1 && event.target.parentNode != dp1){
    dp1.css({height:'0px', width:'0px'});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("mouseup", function(event) {
    var dp1 = $("#dp1");
    var target = $(event.target); 

    if( !$(target).is(dp1) && !target.parents('#dp1').length) {
      dp1.css("height", "0").css("width", "0");
    }
  });
});
```